# Python tags in index.html ignored in Django project

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I have the following in my views.py file

```
def index(request):
    all_destinations = Destination.objects.all()
    template = loader.get_template('plan/index.html')
    context = {
        'all_destinations': all_destinations,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

and the following index.html file in my templates directory.

```
<ul>
    {% for destination in all_destinations %}
    <li><a href="/plan/{{ destination.id }}/"> {{ destination.destination_title }} </a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

The issue is anything between the {% %} and {{ }} tags is ignored by the browser. Any tips on why is this happening?

Comment: Do you actually have any Destination objects in your db?

Comment: Yes I do. I believe the issue is related to the tags because they don't appear when I Inspect the page.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Why would you expect to see the tags?

Comment: I am new to html and I had the impression that the python code would appear in the inspect element. I managed to solve the problem however. The attribute destination_title was not in the Destination model.